# Removing python2-dev dependency break installtion of aws-sam-cli

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile

In the below docker file:

```
  FROM alpine:latest
  ENV HOME /home/samcli
  ENV PATH $HOME/.local/bin:$PATH 
  RUN mkdir /root/bin /aws; \ apk add --no-cache groff less bash python jq curl py-pip tzdata 
  RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
  RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc python2-dev python3-dev linux-headers musl-dev && \ pip install --upgrade pip; \ adduser samcli -Du 5566; \ chown -R samcli $HOME; USER samcli WORKDIR $HOME
  RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli; USER root 
  RUN apk del .build-deps; \ rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

---

We would like to remove `python2-dev` dependency, because python2 will be deprecated after Jan 2020.

How to remove python2 dependency?

Comment: Just remove `python2-dev` package from the `apk add` command and rebuild the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing `Python2-dev` will break the installation of `aws-sam-cli` with error `ERROR: aws-sam-cli 0.19.0 has requirement PyYAML~=3.12, but you'll have pyyaml 5.1 which is incompatible.`

To overcome this error you need to install the `PyYAML==3.12`, but again you will need more dependency to make this installation successfully so I will recommend using python base image to avoid installation of these [bulk dependecny](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.7/alpine3.9/Dockerfile) in your Dockerfile.

Another thing, `apk add --no-cache groff less bash python` this will install `python2` not `python3`so by removing python-dev2 is meaningless.

Here is the working DockerFile which have fix for `ERROR: aws-sam-cli 0.19.0 has requirement PyYAML~=3.12, but you'll have pyyaml 5.1 which is incompatible`

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9

ENV HOME /home/samcli
ENV PATH $HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps  python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev && \
    adduser samcli -Du 5566; \
    chown -R samcli $HOME;
RUN apk add --no-cache groff less bash jq curl py-pip tzdata
RUN pip install PyYAML==3.12
USER samcli

WORKDIR $HOME
RUN pip install --user --upgrade awscli aws-sam-cli;
USER root

RUN apk del .build-deps; \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```